# popen fails with "sh: <command>: not found"

Tags: php, shell, popen, sh

I'm developing a server application and I recently encountered this wierd error on a testing server (Debian Squeeze).

Every executable I pass to **popen** fails with a msg:

```
sh: sort: not found // happens to any command
```

This happens regardless whether I point to the full path returned by "type" or keep it short .
As mentioned earlier, this happens at only one testing environment, to add confusion, am running the same OS and had no problem whatsoever.

Popen is apparently using *sh* to execute commands, but if I run the same command thru the command-line (bash or sh), everything's fine

Thanks in advance

(PS: even tried Python os.popen just to nail this head scratcher, and it works!)

**Edit**
this is a simple call that fails:

```
$command="tail -10 myfile";
$handle = popen($command.' 2>&1','r');
if($handle){
  while (!feof($handle)){
  ....//process buffer
  }
}
```

returns:

```
sh: tail: not found
```

Comment: Please post the actual call, and if uses any variables show how they're generated.

Comment: The result it's the same using the full path of the binary ? (I mean: whereis tail)

Comment: yes, as long as its run thru popen, sh returns that error msg..

Comment: Did you tried to run it from cli as superuser ?

Comment: running it through the CLI is no problem, you dont even need to be a superuser, but the same command fails with POPEN, thats the issue -.-

Answer (score 1):

Probably your PATH is NOT configured properly, when calling popen. I guess this is a PHP configuration problem, but you can bypass it by:

1. Run `which tail` to determine the full path to the tail program.
2. Call `popen` with the path found in 1.

Comment: This is the first thing I tried. The "type" command is similar to "which" on Debian and gives the full path.. but to no avail.. popen still persists on "not found", which is quite perplexing at this point..

Answer (score 0):

I found this question while searching for my own answer regarding the exact same output. Although I am coding in C, I am still using popen(). I am a beginner in C, and discovered that I made the following mistake.

I am answering this in the hope it may be useful to others searching for the same error message. This is how I encountered, discovered, and corrected the problem.

I declared a string and concatenated other strings with it to formulate my command line.

I printed the line to stdout to verify it was the command I wanted. When copied from stdout and executed, the line worked. So why did the shell choke from popen()?

I piped the output to a file and opened the file in an editor, and saw that when my empty string was initialized, the special character '^A' was created with the string, which was not displayed on the terminal.

I changed the way I declared the char array from this:

char varname[];

to this:

char varname[512] = {""};

This resolved the issue. I would encourage anyone with a similar problem to look for hidden characters in the string used with popen().